# Labyrinth of stones

Tags: wordplay, mazes, sliding-blocks

**Help Princess PurpleSprite navigate through the labyrinth to retrieve the mystical jewel.  She can slide the lettered stones around as needed, but she must not leave any non-words, or the labyrinth will collapse!**

[image: labyrinth_of_stones]

The movement should be intuitive, but for those who prefer it to be spelled out:

1. There is one spacer in the labyrinth.
2. Princess PurpleSprite occupies the spacer and moves with it.
3. She can slide any neighboring lettered stone into the spacer, thus advancing the spacer.
4. The unlettered stone is solid rock and does not move.
5. While the spacer is in the midst of a word, it cannot be perceived by the labyrinth.  But the moment the spacer leaves the word, the labyrinth sees it and must observe that it is a true word, or the labyrinth will collapse.
6. All words read horizontally, from left to right.
7. When the spacer is adjacent to the jewel, the Princess can grasp it and then retrace her steps back to the entry.  The reverse journey does not need to be presented.

**Example of the movement**

Within the initial state, we see:

```
    █ENTRY
    SMILED
    BALKED
```

The Princess can move the spacer down by sliding the "S" up.  This leaves the word SENTRY.

```
    SENTRY
    █MILED
    BALKED
```

She then moves the spacer right by pulling consecutive stones to the left.  Remember, as long as she is in the midst of the word, the labyrinth will not see it.

```
    SENTRY
    M█ILED
    BALKED


    SENTRY
    MI█LED
    BALKED
```

After pulling two stones to the left, she stops her rightward movement.  She now moves the spacer down by sliding the "L" up.  This leaves the word MILLED.

```
    SENTRY
    MILLED
    BA█KED
```

And so on.

Text-only version:

```
###SIMPLICITY##UTTERS
#EATING#BELLIES#ROUTE
WARNED#####HEFT##ARCH
SEARING####PLATED#AWL
 ENTRY##BETTOR###READ
SMILED#GREASE###CORES
BALKED#SPOON###DELUDE
#INLET##FILL#MAGE#NOT
####PLEAS##TALON##IT
```

Comment: Which dictionary are you using to define "word"?

Comment: @bobble — All words formed should be quite familiar.  If you feel the need to reach for a dictionary, you've probably gone down the wrong path...

Comment: Just trying to make the question more well-defined. Relying on people's perception of "familiar" words is subjective, so concrete definitions of "word" are encouraged here.

Comment: Does being on the left or right side of a word count as being in the "midst" of it?

Comment: @Deusovi — Yes, because you are still in the process of forming it, still occupying its space.  E.g., see my example:  _MILED is not a word.  The princess is still standing in it.

Comment: Very interesting puzzle design. I especially like the need for retracement in certain places. The fact that there's a "sliding blocks" tag indicates to me that this kind of puzzle design has been around for a while, but it's the first time I've seen it, so... well done. :)

Comment: @COTO — Thank you!  The classic sliding tile puzzle uses numbers rather than letters:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting state:

```
   SIMPLICITY  UTTERS
 EATING BELLIES ROUTE
WARNED     HEFT  ARCH
SEARING    PLATED AWL
@ENTRY  BETTOR   READ
SMILED GREASE   CORES
BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
 INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
    PLEAS  TALON  IT
```

Princess PurpleSprite should go:

> Up to get sentry
>
> ```
>    SIMPLICITY  UTTERS
>  EATING BELLIES ROUTE
> WARNED     HEFT  ARCH
> @EARING    PLATED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by two then up to get earring
>
> ```
>    SIMPLICITY  UTTERS
>  EATING BELLIES ROUTE
> WA@NED     HEFT  ARCH
> EARRING    PLATED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by one then up to get wanted
>
> ```
>    SIMPLICITY  UTTERS
>  EA@ING BELLIES ROUTE
> WANTED     HEFT  ARCH
> EARRING    PLATED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Up to get easing
>
> ```
>    @IMPLICITY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELLIES ROUTE
> WANTED     HEFT  ARCH
> EARRING    PLATED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by eight then down to get implicitly
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BEL@IES ROUTE
> WANTED     HEFT  ARCH
> EARRING    PLATED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by two then down to get beliefs
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HE@T  ARCH
> EARRING    PLATED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Down to get heat
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAT  ARCH
> EARRING    PL@TED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by one then up to get pelted
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     H@AT  ARCH
> EARRING    PELTED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by one then down to get halt
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HALT  ARCH
> EARRING    PE@TED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by one then up to get petted
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HAL@  ARCH
> EARRING    PETTED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by two then down to get heal
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    P@TTED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTOR   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Down to get potted
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BETT@R   READ
> SMILED GREASE   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Down to get better
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BETTER   READ
> SMILED GREAS@   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by one then up to get greats
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BET@ER   READ
> SMILED GREATS   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by one then down to get beater
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BEATER   READ
> SMILED GRE@TS   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by one then up to get greets
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  B@ATER   READ
> SMILED GREETS   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by two then down to get batter
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREE@S   CORES
> BALKED SPOON   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Down to get greens
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPOO@   DELUDE
>  INLET  FILL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Down to get spool
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPOOL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FIL@ MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by two then up to get foil
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SP@OL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FOIL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by one then down to get spoil
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPOIL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FO@L MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Left by one then up to get fool
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SP@IL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FOOL MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Right by two then down to get spill
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPILL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FOO@ MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  TALON  IT
> ```

> Down to get foot
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPILL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FOOT MAGE NOT
>     PLEAS  @ALON  IT
> ```

> Right by four then up to get along
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPILL   DELUDE
>  INLET  FOOT MA@E NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Up to get made
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORES
> BALKED SPILL   @ELUDE
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Right by five then up to get eludes
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   READ
> SMILED GREENS   CORE@
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Up to get cored
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AWL
> SENTRY  BATTER   REA@
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Up to get real
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  ARCH
> EARRING    POTTED AW@
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Left by two then up to get raw
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUTE
> WANTED     HEAL  A@CH
> EARRING    POTTED RAW
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Right by two then up to get ache
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTTERS
>  EASING BELIEFS ROUT@
> WANTED     HEAL  ACHE
> EARRING    POTTED RAW
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Left by four then up to get trout
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  U@TERS
>  EASING BELIEFS TROUT
> WANTED     HEAL  ACHE
> EARRING    POTTED RAW
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Right by three then down to get uterus
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TRO@T
> WANTED     HEAL  ACHE
> EARRING    POTTED RAW
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Left by two then down to get tarot
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  @CHE
> EARRING    POTTED RAW
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Right by three then down to get chew
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  CHEW
> EARRING    POTTED RA@
> SENTRY  BATTER   REAL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Left by two then down to get era
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  CHEW
> EARRING    POTTED ERA
> SENTRY  BATTER   R@AL
> SMILED GREENS   CORED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Left by one then down to get oral
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  CHEW
> EARRING    POTTED ERA
> SENTRY  BATTER   ORAL
> SMILED GREENS   C@RED
> BALKED SPILL   ELUDES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Down to get cured
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  CHEW
> EARRING    POTTED ERA
> SENTRY  BATTER   ORAL
> SMILED GREENS   CURED
> BALKED SPILL   EL@DES
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NOT
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Right by three then down to get eldest
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  CHEW
> EARRING    POTTED ERA
> SENTRY  BATTER   ORAL
> SMILED GREENS   CURED
> BALKED SPILL   ELDEST
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NO@
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

> Down to reach the gem, leaving "no" behind
>
> ```
>    IMPLICITLY  UTERUS
>  EASING BELIEFS TAROT
> WANTED     HEAL  CHEW
> EARRING    POTTED ERA
> SENTRY  BATTER   ORAL
> SMILED GREENS   CURED
> BALKED SPILL   ELDEST
>  INLET  FOOT MADE NO
>     PLEAS  ALONG  IT
> ```

What's astonishing about this puzzle is how hard it must have been to create, since

> Almost every move along the solution path is forced. There are some options near the beginning, but they quickly winnow down after you get to the simplicity -> implicitly transition. Towards the end, there are not many words near elude by going down, so it needs to be transformed by heading upwards instead.

Comment: "how hard it must have been to create..."  You got that right, friend!  It was a lot of careful programming, especially for the second and third sections.  People typically expect their mazes to have numerous branching dead-ends, but forced paths are often more difficult to create (and more fun to solve, I think!)

Comment: A very fun solve :)

Comment: Wouldn't force-path be less fun to solve since there is only one possible way to go? (still a really nice puzzle! just curious)

Comment: @justhalf — You are correct, if the forced path is clear and simple, it is very boring.  It's just a stroll in the park.  But if the forced path is tough or challenging, or unclear, or it SEEMS like you have choices but you really don't, or it takes you along an interesting and unexpected route, then it can be more fun.  See here for an interesting forced-path adventure:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112231/escape-across-the-floorboards

Comment: Ooh, you're right. It does feel satisfying!